# Suggestion of article or book for convolution

Tags: reference-request, convolution, neural-networks

I need a good book or article to learn about convolution.I have a course in Neural Networks and we have to make calculations by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few references concerning convolutions, *specifically regarding their applications to deep networks and machine learning*:

- [*A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning* by Dumoulin and Visin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285)
- [*An Introduction to Convolutional Neural Networks* by O'Shea and Nash](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08458)
- [Chapter 9, Convolutional Networks](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) in the [*Deep Learning* book by Goodfellow et al](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

---

I also like the way presented [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/readings/L11%20Convolutional%20Networks.pdf). Convolution (in 2D) can be written:
$$ (I\ast K)(s,t) = F_I(s,t|K) = \sum_{\alpha,\beta} I(s-\alpha,t-\beta) K(\alpha,\beta) $$
where $I$ is the image (signal) and $K$ is the kernel (filter). We can think of this operation as generating the filtered output $F_I$ by copying local parts of $I$ over and over, each time translating and scaling it based on the values in $K$. Or, we can think of it getting each entry by flipping $K$, and then iteratively shifting it over $I$, taking the dot product at each point (across both dimensions).

Note that most deep learning frameworks actually do not do convolution. They perform cross-correlation. [There is a difference](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/the-difference-between-convolution-and-cross-correlation-from-a-signal-analysis). (It is why $K$ has to be *flipped* in the paragraph above, before computing the sliding "dot products", while many ML implementations will not do this. This can be confusing if you need to go into the details.)